# Optimization of correlation calculation

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, matrix

How can I make the following line of code run faster? Is there a way to do this calculation as a matrix vs vector than vector vs vector?

In the code below, `f` is a matrix with one more row than `vector`. `f` has many columns and `vector` has only one column.

```
vector=RandomReal[1,100000];
f=RandomReal[1,{100001,520}];
pearson = Map[Correlation[f[[2 ;;, #]], vector] &, Range[5, Dimensions[f][[2]]]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's separate sampling from the computation.

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123];
 vector = RandomReal[1, 100000];
 f = RandomReal[1, {100001, 520}];
 ]
```

Here is doing it your way:

```
In[18]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 pearson2 = 
   Map[Correlation[f[[2 ;;, #]], vector] &, 
    Range[5, Dimensions[f][[2]]]];]

Out[18]= {5.865713, Null}
```

Of course you lose of standartization of `vector`. The solution is to use `Correlation` of two matrices:

```
In[19]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 pearson1 = Correlation[f[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]], Transpose[{vector}]];
 ]

Out[19]= {3.229262, Null}
```

Results are equal, of course:

```
In[20]:= Norm[pearson1 - pearson2]

Out[20]= 7.37439*10^-16
```

Comment: excellent.. that is exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot!